# MySQL 8.0: Error when inserting date data

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, datetime, load-data-infile

I have a tab separated file as follows:

[image]

When i try to import the file as follows in MySql:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/customer.csv'
INTO TABLE customers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I get the following error:

> Incorrect date value: '02/15/2008' for column 'BI_signup_date' at row 1

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of dates in your file do not match the format expected by MySQL. Also you have some non-date values in that column (`'not BI'`). A solution is to preprocess your input to transform it to the relevant format.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/customer.csv'
INTO TABLE customers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(customer_id, @BI_signup_date, email_address)
SET BI_signup_date = CASE
    WHEN @BI_signup_date = 'not BI' THEN NULL
    ELSE STR_TO_DATE(@BI_signup_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
END;
```

This will turn value `'not BI'` to `NULL`(since obviously this cannot be converted to a date), and convert other values to MySQL date format. Other strategies are possible, like checking the format of the value against a regex. You can modify the logic as needed.

Reference: [Input preprocessing in MySQL `LOAD DATA` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing):

> Each `col_name_or_user_var` value is either a column name or a user variable. With user variables, the `SET` clause enables you to perform preprocessing transformations on their values before assigning the result to columns.

Comment: I used this and I am getting the following error now: ERROR 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: 'not BI' for function str_to_date

Comment: @AlhpaDelta: is there an issue with the query? It was unaccepted and downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, this does get the data in, But the 4th row and 8th row, which are immediately following the rows where the 'not BI' dates are are not getting uploaded properly. When I do "select * from customers" or "select customer_id,email_address" from customers", the output does not show the customer_id. 
When I do select customer_id,BI_signup_date,email_address from customers WHERE customer_id =8
again there is no customer_id in the output

Comment: when i do "select customer_id,BI_signup_date,email_address from customers WHERE customer_id =8"
or "select customer_id,BI_signup_date,email_address from customers WHERE customer_id =4", the output is correct, except that the customer_id is not being printed!! which is weird. I was wondering why this is happneing

Comment: @AlhpaDelta: well, if a statement like `select ... where customer_id = 8` returns a record, it means that the corresponding `customer_id` is *properly loaded* into the table, right? It looks like you actually have a problem to *display* the data...

Comment: yes, I agree. I apologize. I have checked it. But it is not letting me upvote. saying it is locked in unless the answer is edited.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your csv file and convert the date format to Y-m-d.
This is will resolve all of your issue regarding date format.